# Scala: Splitting the data coming from kafka vi a DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, dstream

I am receiving the data from kafka in the form of

```
{"email":"test@example","firstname":"Example","lastname":"User"}
```

I want to access the email id and first name and want to compare it with data coming from cassandra in the form of :

```
CassandraRow{email: abc@xyz.com}
```

Comment: Can you expand your question - what should be the result of this comparison? How do you fetch data from Cassandra? What is the schema for Cassandra table?

Comment: I want to compare the credentials (email id and name) and if they are same I want to send a message to kafka topic that they are equal. I am fetching data from cassandra table using the variable of SparkStreaming with the line 
val data1 = ssc.cassandraTable("test","login").select("email","name","lastname")

.where("email=?","abc@xyz.com")


val rddQueue = new Queue[RDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]]()

val dstream = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue)


Also my cassandra table has entries for email id, name and last name

Comment: What is the primary key for table?

Comment: email is the primary key

Comment: Please add the extra information you posted in your comment to the actual question

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform join with Cassandra using the [`joinWithCassandraTable` function](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#repartitioning-rdds-based-on-a-cassandra-tables-replication)...

To be more effective, you may need to re-partition your RDD that you get from Kafka to match partitions inside Cassandra's table.  The code could look like this:

```
val resultRdd = kafkaRDD.repartitionByCassandraReplica("ks","emails")
   .joinWithCassandraTable("ks","emails")
```

And after that you can analyze, if names matches, etc. And after join you should get only records for which there are emails in the Cassandra...

Comment: val lines=KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc,kafkaParams,topics).map(_._2).

I am getting this directStream from kafka so how should I re-partition this RDD to apply the operation joinwithcassandraTable and in what form is the value of the variable resultRdd